# Different Result of code when used in Update function

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I have a query which is a combination of Kusto and python code using the python plugin. 
This query is used in a function which is used in the update policy of a table B for updating this table based on another table A.

The result I get when I use the query directly on table A and view the results of this and the entries of table B should be the same but they are not.

The query is working correctly when used directly on table A but not as an update function.

Is there any explanation for this?

Here are some more information:

The update policy was set with:

```
.alter table B policy update @
'[{"IsEnabled": true, "Source": "A", "Query": "Update_groups()", "IsTransactional": false}]'
```

The ingestionbatch policy is set with:

```
.alter table groups_detection policy ingestionbatching @
'{  "MaximumBatchingTimeSpan": "00:10:00",  "MaximumNumberOfItems": 50000, "MaximumRawDataSizeMB": 1024}'
```

The function is a stored function and was set with

```
.create-or-alter function with (folder = "Update", skipvalidation = "true") Update_tableB() 
{
let …;
let…;
A
|where...
|...
| evaluate python(typeof(*),...
||order by timestamp desc
}
```

The results in table B generated by the update function are not correct. The python code seems not to be working like it should but if I use the function body as a single query on table A I get the correct results.

So I am confused where to start looking for the error.

Comment: please add more information to the question so as to help people understand the problem better.

Comment: Please share a minimal repro of the issue. Right now there is not enough information to respond.

Comment: I have added some information above. I hope it is helpful. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> *The result I get when I use the query directly on table A and view the results of this and the entries of table B should be the same but they are not.*

IIUC, it sounds like the comparison you're making isn't 'apples-to-apples'.

- the query in an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy), which is being triggered to run as part of ingesting a batch of records, is scoped to only 'see' the records ingested in that batch.

  - from the docs:

    > *The update policy's query is run in a special mode, in which it "sees" only the newly ingested data to the source table. It isn't possible to query the source table's already-ingested data as part of this query. Doing so quickly results in quadratic-time ingestions.*
- i.e.:

  - when you run this, *not* as part of an update policy: `T | evaluate python (...)`
    the input to the python plugin is *all* the records in the table named `T`.
  - when you specify the exact same query (`T | evaluate python (...)`) as part of your update policy, when it's triggered by an ingestion operation, it will run only on a subset of records in `T` (only those that have just been ingested).

Now, if you want to ingest the results of this query (`T | evaluate python (...)`), where the input is *all* the records in the table named `T`, you can use [ingestion-from-query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) (e.g. run a `.set-or-append` command), and not use an update policy.